# JavaFX custom ChoiceBox not instantiated at startup

Tags: javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

I'am coding a JavaFX application. I created the GUI with SceneBuilder 8.2.
I already put some ChoiceBox but with Java Type, not custom Type.
And it works well.
But with custom Type, the choiceBox is not instantiated, why ?
Below the code :

```
public class PelController {
    //instanciation is OK
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<PeriodeEnum> fCalculInteret;

    //not instanciated at launch
   @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<DureeChoiceBoxElement> duree;

/**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
//fCalculInteret is NOT NULL, automatically instantiated at startup.
fCalculInteret.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(pel.fCalculInteretProperty());
//duree is NULL causing NullPointerException
duree.valueProperty().get().dureeProperty().bindBidirectional(pel.dureeProperty());
    }
}
```

The custom Type :

```
public class DureeChoiceBoxElement extends ObservableValueBase<DureeChoiceBoxElement> {

    private IntegerProperty duree;

    public DureeChoiceBoxElement() {

    }

    public DureeChoiceBoxElement(int duree) {
        this.duree = new SimpleIntegerProperty(duree);
    }

    public IntegerProperty dureeProperty() {
        return duree;
    }

    public Integer getDuree() {
        return duree.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public DureeChoiceBoxElement getValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new DureeChoiceBoxElement(duree.get());
    }

    public void setDuree(Integer duree) {
        this.duree.setValue(duree);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return duree + " an";
    }

}
```

Can you explain why this NullPointer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
duree.valueProperty().get().dureeProperty().bindBidirectional(pel.dureeProperty());        

                                 |                                    |
```

->Nulls maybe comes from `|`

Hm it seems that  the method:

```
 public IntegerProperty dureeProperty() {
        return duree;
 }
```

returns null cause the default constuctor doesn't initialize the `duree` property.

---

1)One solution is to modify the method to:

```
//lazy
public IntegerProperty dureeProperty() {
       if(duree == null) //if duree has not been initialized
         duree = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        return duree;
}
```

---

or 2)You can change the **default constructor** to initialize the `private IntegerProperty duree;` property , although solution 1 is better.

Comment: The NULL pointer comes from the variable : private ChoiceBox<DureeChoiceBoxElement> duree; "duree" is NULL whereas I put @FXML annotation like other ChoiceBox

Comment: @François F. I mean `private IntegerProperty duree;` .Try to replace the code with the provided one and if it doesn't work , add an error stacktrace on the question :)

Comment: My mistake for the duree ChoiceBox, problem was in FXML file. But to answer you, look that I set a bindDirectional. In this way I want another IntegerProperty allows to select the right DureeChoiceBoxElement item comparing with private IntegerProperty duree; value. I am trying this way. Thanks.

Comment: @ François F. Without stack trace i can't guess everything :) . Also what is the `pel`  in `duree.valueProperty().get().dureeProperty().bindBidirectional(pel.dureeProperty());` ? Although i recommend to provide `lazy evaluation` in your code... to avoid future null pointers.